# Impose max limit in Loopback

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is there a way to set a max limit in Loopback.  I imagine something like this:

```
MyModel.paginateFind = function(filter, page, cb){

    // Set max limit of 1000
    if (filter.limit > 1000) filter.limit = 1000;

    // Set pagination
    filter.skip = filter.limit * (page - 1);

    // Call the standard find function with the new filter
    MyModel.find(filter, function(err, res){
        cb(err, res);
    });
}

MyModel.remoteMethod(
    'paginatedFind',
    {
        http: {path: '/', verb: 'get'},
        accepts: [
            {arg: 'filter', type: 'object'},
            {arg: 'page',   type: 'number'}
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'}
    }
);
```

This works when the filter is formated as json, but not in this format: `http://localhost:3000/api/MyModel?filter=[where][country]=DE`. How can I use the standard StongLoop filter format?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the `limit filter` which goes hand in hand with the `skip filter`? http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Limit+filter

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to manipulate the filter in a custom function/end-point in the model.  I'm sure it's something super simple.

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks pretty accurate~ish to me ... have you asked on https://gitter.im/strongloop/loopback already?

Answer (score 0):

The format, according the to documentation [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter) should look like this:

```
api/MyModel?filter[where][country]=DE
```